# Why cannot I become root via `su`?

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, root, su

Why doesn't `su` work but `sudo -i` does? When I want to become root via `su`, the system doesn't accept my password, but via `sudo -i` it works.

```
su: Authentication failure
```

Comment: What is the distribution? Does the root account have the  password disabled? Some distributions have it by default.

Comment: Debian buster, If it's disabled, how can I enable it again ? Why it works with sudo -i

Comment: Running `sudo -i` is kind of like `sudo bash`, just with whatever shell was in `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set/change the root password:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Then you will be able to run `su` command.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is found in the sudoers man page (type `man sudoers` to see the complete page):

```
Unlike su(1), when sudoers requires authentication, it validates
the invoking user's credentials, not the target user's (or root's)
credentials.
```

So `sudo` is asking for your password, and `su` is asking for root password.

**The long answer**

`su` means **change user**, as in, start a shell as that user.  You can specify which user, such as `su someuser`.  You are then prompted for `someuser`'s password.  If you don't specify a user, `su` defaults to the root user.  So when you type `su`, it is asking for the root password.

`sudo` means, **run a command as another user**, and `sudo -i` means, run a login shell as another user.  You can specify which user, but if you don't, it defaults to root.  Instead of expecting the password of the other user like `su` does, `sudo` applies a security policy.  The default security policy is to check the file `/etc/sudoers`.  The default version of that file includes this:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

which means that, if the user is in the `sudo` group, it can run any command as any user.  If `sudo -i` works for you, it's probably because your own account is in the sudo group.  But before `sudo` executes the command, it asks for **your** password again—not the password of the root user.